# SQL Self Recursive Join with Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have the following table:

```
Name   New_Name 
---------------
A         B
B         C
C         D
G         H
H         I
Z         B
```

I want to create a new table that links all the names that are related to a single new groupID

```
GroupID  Name
-------------
1         A
1         B
1         C
1         D
1         Z
2         G
2         H
2         I
```

I'm a bit stuck on this can can't figure out how to do it apart from a bunch of joins. But I would like to do it properly.

Edited the question to allow grouping from two different start points, A and Z into one group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've changed the question, I'm updating the answer. Please note that answer is same in sense of logical structure. All it does differently is that instead of going from G to I in calculating levels, answer now calculates from I to G.

<kbd>**[Working demo link](http://rextester.com/UPL4036)**</kbd>

```
;with cte as
( 
    select 
       t1.Name as Name, row_number() over (order by t1.Name) r,
       t1.New_Name as New_Name,
       1 as level 
    from yt t1 left join  yt t2
       on t1.New_Name=t2.name
    where t2.name is null
     union all
    select 
       yt.Name as Name, r,
       yt.New_Name as New_Name,
       c.level+1 as level
    from cte c  join yt
       on yt.New_Name=c.Name
   ),
   cte2 as 
   (   
     select r as group_id, Name from cte
     union
     select c1.r as group_id, c1.New_name as Name from cte c1
       where level = (select min(level) from cte c2 where c2.r=c1.r)
     )


 select * from cte2;
```

> Below is old answer.

You can try below CTE based query:

```
create table yt (Name varchar(10),  New_Name varchar(10));
insert into yt values
('A','B'),
('B','C'),
('C','D'),
('G','H'),
('H','I');

;with cte as
( 
    select 
       t1.Name as Name, row_number() over (order by t1.Name) r,
       t1.New_Name as New_Name,
       1 as level 
    from yt t1 left join  yt t2
       on t1.Name=t2.New_name
    where t2.new_name is null
     union all
    select 
       yt.Name as Name, r,
       yt.New_Name as New_Name,
       c.level+1 as level
    from cte c  join yt
       on yt.Name=c.New_Name
   ),
 cte2 as 
 (   
   select r as group_id, Name from cte
   union
   select c1.r as group_id, c1.New_name as Name from cte c1
     where level = (select max(level) from cte c2 where c2.r=c1.r)
   )


 select * from cte2;
```

**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/UPL4036)**

Comment: I had to modify the question as it wasn't complete clear. So this result works, except if I add the values ('Z','B') see edit it will create two groups(Group 1 and Group 3), and not group Z into Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit complex but working.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE  (Name VARCHAR(2),   New_Name VARCHAR(2))
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
('A','B'),
('B','C'),
('C','D'),
('G','H'),
('H','I'),
('Z','B')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) FROM @T
)
,CTE2 AS (SELECT T1.RN, T1.Name Name1, T1.New_Name New_Name1, 
                 X.Name Name2, X.New_Name New_Name2, 
                 FLAG = CASE WHEN X.Name  IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
          FROM CTE T1
          OUTER APPLY (SELECT  * FROM CTE T2 WHERE T2.RN > T1.RN 
                       AND (T2.Name IN (T1.Name , T1.New_Name) 
                            OR T2.New_Name IN (T1.Name , T1.New_Name)
                       ))  AS X
)
,CTE3 AS (SELECT *, 
    GroupID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RN) -
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Flag ORDER BY RN) +1
    FROM CTE2
)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT GroupID, Name 
FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM CTE3 WHERE Name2 IS NOT NULL) SRC 
  UNPIVOT ( Name FOR COL IN ([Name1], [New_Name1], [Name2], [New_Name2])) UNPVT
```

Result

```
GroupID              Name
-------------------- ----
1                    A
1                    B
1                    C
1                    D
1                    Z
2                    G
2                    H
2                    I
```